# How to make select dropdown with search box for options in vuejs 3 with options api?

Tags: javascript, select, vuejs3

**I want to make like bootstrap select search box with dropdown for options in `Vue.js 3`**

In bootstrap, we can do this by adding cdn css and js.

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

So here, what would be the best options for this solution? How can I select options (filters) by typing the options from the list.

I found the `vue-select`, `vue-next-select`, `vue-search-select` but these didn't worked. I am using `bootstrap 5` and `Vue.js 3`

I found `vue-next-select` package for vue.js. In its documentation - it has for compositions api with typescript. But I could not find anywhere for options api with javascript.

The following select form need to converted to select dropdown and search (local search is fine too)

```
<select class="form-control" v-model="patient.hospital_id" name="hospital_id" required>
  <option value="" selected>Select Hospital</option>
  <option v-for="hos in hospitals" :key="hos.id" :value="hos.id">{{ hos.name }}</option>
</select>
```

In Vue.js 3 - I have script this to get hosptials.

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
      return {
          hospitals:{},
      }
  },
  created() {        
    this.$axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(response => {
      this.$axios.get('/api/users/getHospital')
          .then(response => {
              this.hospitals = response.data;
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
              console.error(error);
          });
      })
  },
  methods: {
    addTelemedicine() {
      //
    }
  }, 

}
</script>
```

Hospitals result will be like this `[ { "id": 1, "name": "BPKIHS" }, { "id": 2, "name": "Dharan Health post" } ]`

I will appreciate for your help. Thanks

Comment: `vue-next-select` should work with Vue 3. How did it not work for you?